# Prevent caching on ASP MVC site running on IIS 7.5

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, iis, caching

I have an ASP MVC 3 site running on IIS 7.5 and I cant prevent it from caching.

I have disabled the output caching in IIS by adding a '* Do Not Cache' entry to the website and also added an action filter on the controller on result execute that prevents caching too (see code below) but when I use the site, it's still caching.  I have deleted all history and cookies etc from Internet Explorer and Firefox but I still see old data.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on what else I can do to try and prevent this?

Thanks in advance,

James

**UPDATE**

I have dug further using the SQL profiler and it seems to be the SQL server caching the query.  Could this be the case?

**2nd UPDATE**

I now know if definitley NOT SQL caching, now looking at IIS and MVC

**SOLVED!!!**

It was NHibernate!

It was using the same session for every call rather than a session per request.

```
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation    (HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

Comment: Are you entirely sure the data isn't just old itself? I'm pretty sure MVC won't just cache everything by default. I don't recall ever running into that problem

Comment: Hi Jimmy - yes i am certain.  The data get updated and I can see that in SQL using managment studio but the site still displays old data.

Comment: Jimmy is right. MCV should not cache by default and neither should IIS. Can you be more specific on what you are doing? What operations does your code perform and what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 2):

you could try adding OutputCach attribute to the action and set the duration to a couple seconds.
Ex:
[OutputCache(Duration=1, VaryByParam = "none")]

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling your MVC action via JQuery ajax? If so, see this: http://www.peteonsoftware.com/index.php/2010/08/20/the-importance-of-jquery-ajaxsetup-cache/

Comment: We are using Ajax (Telerik controls) but we have turned Ajax off and we still get the same stale data

Answer (score 0):

It's not as simple as the problem being in the browser cache itself is it?
try adding a no-cache meta tag?

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
</HEAD><BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Just a thought, also you can set the no-cache header. Maybe use Fiddler to check the browsers not caching the response.

Comment: I will try that but if 2 people log in, they get the same stale data

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!!!**

It was NHibernate!

It was using the same session for every call rather than a session per request.